# Asp.Net how to retrieve JSON from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have created a JSON in jQuery which looks like this:

```
{  
   "objects":[  
      {  
         "ObjectId":1,
         "Line1":"Software",
         "Line2":"Microsoft",
         "Line3":"Web",
         "Line4":"Asp.Net",
         "Line5":"jQuery"
      },
      {  
         "ObjectId":2,
         "Line1":"Hardware",
         "Line2":"Microsoft",
         "Line3":"Computer",
         "Line4":"Surface",
         "Line5":"Pro"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I use AJAX to send it via jQuery to my controller:

```
var postData = { objects: objectArray };

// Fire off the request to controller
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: '/Controller/myAction',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: postData,
    success: function (result) {
        // success handler
    }
})


public ActionResult myAction(???)
{
    return view();
}
```

What I am not sure about is how I receive the object in my controller. Can someone help me with this please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, start by creating a model object to represent the data on the server side

```
public class ObjectModel
{
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public string Line4 { get; set; }
    public string Line5 { get; set; }
}
```

Then define your mvc actions parameter like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myAction(List<ObjectModel> objects)
{
    return view();
}
```

then simply pass the object array as json

```
// Fire off the request to controller
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: '/Controller/myAction',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(objectArray),
    success: function (result) {
        // success handler
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it out. I slightly edited my question. Are you missing ObjectId in the model?

Comment: Worked successfully:) !!

Comment: Sweet! glad to help =)

Answer (score 3):

Just a little lifehack for future: if you have to add new class based on existing JSON or XML model, there are awesome built-in tool in Visual Studio:

[Class generating from JSON/XML models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmqqj.png)

Comment: That's freaking awesome, I've been using http://json2csharp.com/ for the longest time and never knew this was already baked into VS